# Can GBP be directly used in Austria

Tags: exchange, austria

I have GBPs left with me from my last travel to UK. Can I use it directly in Austria or is it advisable to convert all these GBPs to Euro before I travel to Austria? Or can GBPs be easily converted to Euros in Austria itself?

Comment: If your trip is more than 1-2 weeks away, consider getting a revolut.com or transferwise.com debit card (or search for other branchless banks). Their exchange rates are quite good and specified up-front. They can also convert GBP from your account as you make purchases.

Comment: Just curious, why do you think a foreign currency would work "directly" in Austria?

Comment: "can GBPs be easily converted"  if you wish to "get rid of" some paper UKP, one issue you will face is nobody will take the small change or perhaps even the small notes.

Comment: @BruceWayne David's answer describes reasons why certain foreign currencies are commonly accepted in some areas. Granted, as David also noted, none of those apply to Austria with the GBP.

Comment: Can I use Euros directly in the UK?

Comment: @Fattie/BruceWayne The OP _prefers to keep an air of mystery about him_, however, taking a wild guess based on his username, I'd say he/she's not from Europe (India, perhaps?). From that range, Britain and Austria are next-door neighbours with practically identical cultures. It might well be that their currencies are interchangeable... Of course, from our zoomed-in perspective, they're not.

Comment: There are of course countries where you can freely use a different country's currency: Euros in Bosnia, for example, or USD in Mexico. But that's the exception to the rule. Generally, in a country with a strong currency of its own, only businesses catering exclusively to tourists will accept foreign currency.

Comment: @user29850 Yes, at touristy shops (especially in London) and some large department stores and similar where tourists might want to shop (ditto London), though you'll get a lousy exchange rate. Probably many shops close to the border with Ireland will take them. But there's a big difference here: the Eurozone is 340 million Euro-using people, some of whom are right on Britain's doorstep; all of the 65 million users of the British pound are some distance from Austria.

Comment: @OscarBravo This argument doesn't hold water. It would not have crossed my mind for even one second that I could use Indian currency in Pakistan, for example – and, rather obviously, I can't.

Comment: Also GBP has recently changed design. The £5 & £10 note are now a polymer with a see through window (they changed in 2016 & 2017 respectively). You may find changing them tricky unless you use a UK bank.

Answer (score 45):

No, GBP can not be used directly in Austria.
No store will accept them.

You won't have any serious trouble finding a currency exchange store to convert them to Euros though.

Comment: No store except some of the most touristy souvenir shops in the tourist hotspots.

Comment: @Anjali Depending on the amount of GBP you have left, you might want to safe it for your next trip to the UK, because of the conversion fee you have to pay for GBP->EUR. If you don't have a lot of GBP left but you still want to spend it, you might want to consider [this bank in the first district of Vienna](https://www.schelhammer.at/), since they don't charge a fee for conversion, instead their conversion rate is slightly in their favour but that should not make a difference with small amounts.

Comment: Thank you @RobertRiedl. I just need a small clarification regarding exchange rates published on the website you mentioned. Is this published exchange rate I am gonna get for GBP-->EUR conversion. or do I need to pay any additional fees for the exchange transaction. you did mentioned " no conversion fees"- I'm just checking for any other taxes/fees the bank levies on it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RobertRiedl Offering zero commission and making up for it with insane bid-ask spreads is standard for currency exchanges these days... I would expect the exchange at the airport to offer a similar option. (The spread will be even worse at the airport, but as you pointed out, for small amounts it's more about convenience than price.)

Comment: @Sneftel, compared to other banks I think it is the cheapest option, and you will not have a surcharge for only changing 5 GBP to EUR. Other banks will levy a minimum fee/commission. Unfortunately the exchanges places at the airport don't have only exchanges rates, but I doubt they are cheaper. That said, it is always good to compare and you might get a better deal at a bureau de change around the corner. However, this bank is actually somewhat of an insider tip for Vienna tourists, since it is centrally located and offers good rates and no extra fees.

Comment: Guys, this question is about using GPB in Austria. Not how exchange places and banks works.

Comment: @pipe, as I said, the bank mentioned is a tip for tourists in Austria due to location, exchange rate and lack of fees.

Comment: @RobertRiedl: Getting only 0.90405 euro for a pound is an extremely horrible deal. Even with Brexit looming, the pound is still worth _more than_ one euro; one should be getting between 1.10 and 1.15 currently.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, thank you, you are totally right. I think I have misinterpreted the [exchange rates here](https://www.schelhammer.at/de/kompetenzen/gold-edelmetalle-valuten/valuten). If you look at the other exchange rates (i.e. USD) it seems I've got it the wrong way around. The correct values for [this bank](https://www.schelhammer.at/) : 10 GBP would get you ~ 11,8 € and 100 GBP about ~ 110,85 €.

Comment: Changing cash is a disaster, never do it.  If you're just in Austria for a day or two, simply use your credit card.

Comment: @Fattie I doubt the local bakery will accept your credit card for a lunchtime sandwich (except in the *most* touristy spots).  They certainly won't in Germany.

Comment: for cash, get say 200 euros (or whatever you will need) from any cash machine (in Austria) just using your debit card.  it's ridiculously cheaper than changing paper money.

Answer (score 16):

There are a number of reasons that a shop might choose to accept some currency.

- Obviously, they'll accept the local currency.
- If they're in an area where a relatively large fraction of shoppers are tourists from some particular place, they might accept that currency, too. Likewise, if they're very close to an international border, doubly so if, for example, tax regulations make it profitable for people to cross the border to buy alcohol, cigarettes or some other highly taxed product.
- If they're in an area where the local currency and economy are unstable, they might accept some major world currency (typically the US dollar or maybe the Euro) because it's more reliable than their local currency.

None of these situations seem to apply to Austrian shops and British pounds. Obviously, it's not the local currency, there will be many more  more visitors from neighbouring countries (which was kind of the point of the Euro in the first place!) than the UK, and the Euro is a perfectly stable currency to do business in.

Answer (score 2):

An enterprising individual will accept them, but I will rip you off on the exchange rate. Better off converting it elsewhere for cheap. I worked at a souvenir shop around Praterstern during my younger years and I did this numerous times.

Comment: "An enterprising individual will accept them" I wouldn't rely on that. What use are British pounds to the average Austrian shopkeeper or restaurateur?

Comment: Do it a couple of times in a week and I almost always doubled my wages.

Comment: How would accepting GBP instead of Euro for a couple of transactions a week have any meaningful impact on your wages? How would it have _any_ impact?

Comment: If you get enough (with a lousy for the pound user exchange rate) you can take them to a proper exchange office or a bank, or safe them up to use them in the UK at a later date.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - If the item costs €10 but, as the enterprising individual I accept £100 instead, I can then change that £100 into €, pay the €10 into the till and keep the remaining money myself. I think most tourists would be unlikely to do this, and you'd be seen as a bit of a scammer for doing so, but it works as an example for how it could have an impact (and maybe with a massaging of the figures it could actually be acceptable and profitable).

Comment: @Willeke Right, but "a couple of times a week" isn't going to have any significant impact on the business or the shop assistant.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland First, that's an absolutely outrageous rate of exchange (the true rate is very approximately one-to-one, not ten-to-one): it's really hard to imagine anybody being willing to pay £100 for a €10 souvenir and if you ratchet that down to, say, £20, it's hard to imagine "a couple of times a week" being enough to double the shop assistant's salary. Second, any reputable shop would be very unhappy about its staff making side-deals on customer purchases.

Comment: @David Richerby I manipulated exchange rates in my favour. I sized up the customer according to his dress, hair, companion, tattoos/piercings, smartphone and his children. I then gave him a fair exchange rate. He was happy for the convenience of paying with dollars or pounds. Do this repeatedly  and this  microtransactions add up over a month. I might sound like a run of the mill scumbag but teenage me had to get that Golf MK4.

Comment: You can't double your wages with a couple of microtransactions a week. Any chance you could get your story straight before posting it as advice on the internet?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I earned ~500 €...

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Neither of your points matter w.r.t my comment. I was offering it as an example because you said, and I quote "How would it have _any_ impact?" This is an example of how it could have an impact. Don't get hung up on the numbers (although I thought you might get hung up on the numbers, which I didn't calculate to be plausible because it is **an example** not a business plan, hence I offered a little extra comment on needing to massage them to **maybe** make it work).

Comment: First you said it was "a couple of times in a week"; now you're saying it was five times a day. The reason I can't understand you is not because I'm stupid: it's because you change your story every time you comment.

Comment: Thanks, this is potentially useful information for a tourist. Obviously not something you'd want to do with a significant amount of money but if I just had £5 to get rid of, I might rather spend it on a €2 souvenir than go through the hassle of changing it.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland There are no £100 notes, and I would advise anyone in Austria (or in the UK for that matter) not to accept a £50 note, so the largest you should ever encounter in Austria is a £20 note.

Comment: @gnasher729, I never said there was. The point of my example is to show how using accepting different currencies could make money for the store worker doing it, the figures are just for simple examples. You seem to think he's making the money but tricking tourists based on note denomination but that isn't what it's meant to be demonstrating.

Answer (score 2):

In Vienna you might find places to get your money exchanged (some places might try to rip you off, so better be a little bit careful)

Although if you only go to more rural areas in Austria, it could be quite difficult to get your money exchanged. As I grew up in a very rural Area in Austria, I can't recall ever seeing a place that would exchange money outside of the big cities (Vienna, Graz, Salzburg...).